# Add simple items to Maui ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, maui

I'm trying to feed a simple list of items to a ListView (other Android platforms require much less effort).

So, I have this markup:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiApp1.NewPage1"
         Title="NewPage1">


<ScrollView>
    
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button Text="Back;"
              x:Name="cmdBack"
              Clicked="cmdBack_Clicked"
              WidthRequest="100"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               CornerRadius="10"
        
         />

        <Button Text="Load ListView;"
              x:Name="cmdLoad"
              Clicked="cmdLoad_Clicked"
              WidthRequest="100"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               CornerRadius="10"
        
         />

        <ListView x:Name="ListView1" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding myitemname}"
                  Detail="this is some detail text" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>


    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

And code behind is this:

```
public NewPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


private void cmdBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Navigation.PopAsync();

}

private void cmdLoad_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<oneitem> MyItems = new List<oneitem>();    

    for (int i = 1;i <= 3;i++)
    {
        oneitem OneNewitem = new oneitem();
        OneNewitem.myitemname = "This is item " + i.ToString();
        MyItems.Add(OneNewitem);    
    }

    ListView1.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "MyItems");
}
public class oneitem
{
    public string myitemname; 
}
```

When running the above, no code errors, but the ListView does not display data.

So, the goal is to use a simple for/next loop, and feed the ListView a few items based on that simple loop.

The above page results in this:

[image]

So, I'm expecting the result to be:

```
 This is item 1
 This is item 2
 This is item 3
```

How can I make above code work?

Comment: You can only bind to public properties.  MyItems only exists in the scope of the event handler it’s created in.  And myitemname is not a property

Comment: Hum, myitemname is a property of the class oneitem.  Did not think it needs a getter/setter. Are you saying that if I move the class out of the current NewPage class, then it will work? I mean, I just used a class here, but a simple List<string> of items created in code to be displayed would also suffice. It's a simple question of how with a wee bit of code we can send such items created in code to be displayed, and I'm 100% open to a different approach of using code to display a few items.

Comment: if it doesn't have a get/set its not a C# Property, its just a field

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am often OH SO VERY lazy when building quick and dirty classes. And in most cases a public property (aka: field) will suffice. Regardless, I thankful to all here, and below is a great working and simple example......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the items to the [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-8.0) per your requirement, please attend to the items below:

1. Change `MyItems` as `ObservableCollection` like below:

```
public  ObservableCollection<oneitem> MyItems { get; set; } =new ObservableCollection<oneitem>();
```

2. Assign the `ItemsSource` property of the [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-8.0) in the Constructor:

```
ListView1.ItemsSource = MyItems;
```

3. Don't forget setting the `BindingContext` of the Page in code-behind:

```
BindingContext = this;
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
      public  ObservableCollection<oneitem> MyItems { get; set; } =new ObservableCollection<oneitem>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListView1.ItemsSource = MyItems;
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void cmdLoad_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                oneitem OneNewitem = new oneitem();
                OneNewitem.myitemname = "This is item " + i.ToString();
                MyItems.Add(OneNewitem);
            }
        }
    }

    public class oneitem
    {
        public string myitemname { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you VERY kindly, this helps boatloads. I just jumping into maui - only a few hours in. A bit frustrating at first for me. Only saving part is I'm at home with xmal markup. And of course I would/should/will move parts out to a view, but a few "toddler" steps here is much appreciated. I am starting to find maui has "huge" potential here. I done some Android stuff in the past, but I really prefer .net land and using Visual Studio. So, fingers crossed this can work for me, and I'll be beyond happy camper! Again, thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, glad to see you have started your new journey into Maui. You can also refer to the official learning docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-8.0, Good luck! :)